# Community-auth Codeigniter 3 - randomly seems to lose session variable

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I am using Community-Auth with Codeingniter V3 to do authentication and to store authorization levels, etc.

The problem I am having is that my users are sometimes being redirected to the login page, even though they have not been inactive. I cannot seem to isolate a particular behavior or pattern to duplicate the problem.

The problem occurs when a controller calls the verify_min_level routine which should just verify that they are logged on. But it returns FALSE, which means Community-Auth believes they are not logged in, and the code redirects to the login screen.

Since it seems to happen randomly and for no apparent reason (the user was not inactive for a while, etc) it is driving my users crazy.

Has anyone else seen this kind of behavior?

Comment: log every step until it gets logged out

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have identified the problem. This particular client wanted sessions that would only end when they logged out or closed their browser window. So I set the session expiration to zero (0).

I thought that the garbage collection would only delete sessions occasionally (given that in codeigniter I understand that 0 means the session ends in two years) and that I would catch up with it with my own garbage collection. However I started noticing that the ci_sessions table (I moved session data to database from file system to help debug this issue) would have multiple sessions removed frequently, even though none of the sessions were anywhere near two years old.

What seems to have solved the problem is to turn off the garbage collection completely by setting the PHP parameter **sessions.gc_probability** to 0.

No garbage collection, no premature deletion of session variables.

I am implementing a nightly CRON job to do garbage collection of the ci_sessions table.